Issues running npx genkit start
I am trying to play around with Firebase's new Genkit product but whenever I run the npx genkit start command, I get one of two errors:
throw Error(`Unexpected runtime while starting app code: ${runtime}`);

npm ERR! Missing script: "build"


I didn't read the docs and was using an older version of node. Genkit requires Node.js 20 or later.
To fix, this I just updated Node:
nvm install v20.13.1

Then I reran the install command:
npm i -g genkit

And everything worked as expected. Wish the error message was not as cryptic!

First check if genkit is installed globally
npm ls --depth=0 

If genkit is in the list, run below cmd to init
npx genkit init

